# How to use WTForms' TableWidget?

Tags: python, wtforms

I want to use WTForms to render a form in a table. It seems like the [TableWidget](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/widgets.html) will do the trick, but the only way I can get this to work is as follows:

```
from wtforms import Form, TextField, widgets

class User(Form):
    user = TextField('User')
    email = TextField('Password')

    widget = widgets.TableWidget(with_table_tag=False)

user = User()
print user.widget(user)
```

This seems weird (the `print user.widget(user)` part) According to the documentation, I ought to be able to say:

```
class User(Form):
    user = TextField('User', widget=widgets.TableWidget)
    email = TextField('Password', widget=widgets.TableWidget)

user = User()
for form_field in user:
    print form_field
```

However, this returns `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type TableWidget)`

When I replace user, email with:

```
user = TextField('User')
email = TextField('Password')
```

Then of course the WTForms rendering works as expected.

How does this work?

Comment: I know this is old, but none of the two methods works for me, do you know of a different way? All that renders is this: `<wtforms.widgets.core.TableWidget object at 0x109f7cdd0>`

Answer (score 1):

In the docs it says the following about `TableWidget`

> Renders a list of fields as a set of table rows with th/td pairs.

You are associating it a with single field instead of a list of fields. If you look in the code the `__call__` method of `TableWidget` expects an argument called `field` but it treats it as an `iterable` for purposes of generating the html string.